# Trying to build react-native to my device

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to build my react native app. But I keep getting this error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uY9L.jpg)

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' in: C:\sdk
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Answer (score 0):

On **SDK Manager**, be sure to check the box on "**show package descriptions"**; then you should also select the "**Google APIs**" for the version you are willing to install.

Install it and then you should be ok...

hope it'll helps you...

Answer (score 0):

I usually open Android Studio after I setup my react native app, and open the android project from there (choose open, navigate to the app folder, then choose the android app folder inside of it),

- when it loads up you would get prompted to install missing (sdk-23) if you don't have it.
- then also go to project's `build.gradle` file (the one with Top-level build file... text on top) and change the following:

  ```
  buildscript {
      repositories {
          google() //add this
          mavenLocal() //add this
          jcenter()
      }
      dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0' //change this

      // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
      // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }


  }

  allprojects {
      repositories {
          google() //add this
          mavenLocal()
          jcenter()
          maven {
              // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
              url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- hit sync on the yellow toolbar (after project syncs you might be prompted to update the `buildToolsVersion` to `'26.0.2'` do that and sync again.
- Try to run/build your app to emulator